# How to remove "Delete" checkbox on "extra" forms in Django inline formset

Tags: django, inline-formset

I'm using inline formsets in Django, and for each item showing one "extra" form, for adding another object.

The forms for existing objects have "Delete" checkboxes, for removing that object, which makes sense.

But also the "extra" forms have these "Delete" checkboxes... which makes no sense because there's nothing there to delete. Inline forms in the Django admin don't show these "Delete" checkboxes for "extra" forms.

How can I remove these checkboxes on the "extra" inline forms?

The inline formsets part of my template is something like this ([simplified, full version on GitHub](https://github.com/philgyford/django-nested-inline-formsets-example/blob/master/publishing/books/templates/books/publisher_update.html#L54)):

```
{% for bookimage_form in form.forms %}
  {% for hidden_field in bookimage_form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden_field.errors }}
  {% endfor %}

  {{ bookimage_form.as_table }}
{% endfor %}
```

And here's the "Delete" checkbox that seems superfluous:

[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [can_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.can_delete) setting of the `InlineModelAdmin` class (`TabularInline` inherits from `InlineModelAdmin`):

```
class BookImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BookImage
    extra = 1
    can_delete = False
```

Comment: Thanks, but... I don't want to change this in the Admin. And if I set `can_delete=False` when creating the inline formsets with `inlineformset_factory()` then this turns off *all* the Delete checkboxes - I want to keep them on the forms that contain existing objects.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't get that part. I guess that checkbox exists there in case you fill the data in that formset, change your mind and don't want to reset all fields one by one. Would hiding that checkbox with css be an option for you?

Comment: It's possible to hide it with CSS but I'd prefer to do it a "proper" way. And if that's the purpose of that Delete box, why don't the inline forms in the Admin have them? (I'm not expecting you to have the answer!) It's very odd.

Answer (score 4):

Update for Django 3.2+ ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete-extra)), you can now pass in `can_delete_extra` as False to formset_factory or it extended classes to remove checkbox from extra forms

> can_delete_extra  New in Django 3.2.
>
> BaseFormSet.can_delete_extra
>
> Default: True
>
> While setting can_delete=True, specifying can_delete_extra=False will
> remove the option to delete extra forms.

For anyone having Django version under 3.2 and do not wish to upgrade, please use the following method of overriding the BaseFormSet:

```
class CustomFormSetBase(BaseModelFormSet):
        
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        if 'DELETE' in form.fields and form.instance.pk: # check if have instance
            form.fields['DELETE'] = forms.BooleanField(
                label=_('Delete'),
                widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
                    attrs={
                        'class': 'form-check-input'
                    }
                ),
                required=False
            )
        else:
            form.fields.pop('DELETE', None)


YourFormSet = modelformset_factory(
                formset=CustomFormSetBase,
                can_delete=True,
                extra=2
            )
```

*only took them 13 years to add this >.> https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9061*

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to remove the delete checkbox in the official django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

you just have to add 'can_delete=false' as an argument to inlineformset_factory in your views.py file

```
inlineformset_factory(can_delete=false)
```

Comment: Your Code has a syntax error as in python boolean is False not false.
so your code has to be like this.
inlineformset_factory(can_delete=False)

Answer (score 1):

here's a way to get there in the template when you're looping through forms:

```
{% if bookimage_form.instance.pk %}
  <small><b>{{ bookimage_form.DELETE.label_tag }}</b></small><br>
  {{ bookimage_form.DELETE}}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

you won't be able to use the `as_table()` method I don't think, though. You'll have to express every other field in the form.

Here's another thing you could try out after you initialise the form, but before it goes into the context:

```
for f in form.forms: 
    if not f.instance.pk: 
        f.fields['DELETE'] = None
```

Not sure how that'll come out in the table, but you may be able to monkey with the idea.

Answer (score 0):

My suggest is to render the template in nested for loops and add this:

```
 {% if forloop.parentloop.last and forloop.last%}
     not render form filds
 {% else %}
     render field
 {% endif %}
```